# PHP_EOL in Gmail Issue

Tags: php, post, gmail

The following code is the body of a contact form that when submitted is emailed. When I view this output in Gmail, all input data is one one line. I've attempted the PHP_EOL command to insert a line break, but to no luck. Anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly? My goal is to have each post on a new line to make it easier for the user to read.

```
<?PHP
$m->Subject = 'Contact form submitted';
$m->Body = $_POST['cd-name'] . PHP_EOL;
$m->Body .= $_POST['cd-email'] . PHP_EOL;
$m->Body .= $_POST['cd-textarea'];
?>
```

Comment: depends on how you're sending this. as HTML or plain text?

Comment: `php_eol` is the LOCAL eol character. it's useless when building cross-platform text, because the local eol character may mean absolutely NOTHING to the receiving system.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?PHP
$m->Subject = 'Contact form submitted';
$m->Body = "{$_POST['cd-name']}
{$_POST['cd-email']}
{$_POST['cd-textarea']}";
?>
```

Of course, you'll want to sanitize this data before you actually use this code.

Comment: Sorry Jessica. I deleted my comment when I noticed the encapsulated double quotes.